# Is this a bug with action editor?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

Does anyone know what is wrong with my NLA Editor? It says I have a key frame at the end of the animation but clearly it is not there.  What is going on?

[image]

I was able to find the key frame in the timeline instead, but deleting it doesn't seem possible:
[image]

I have expanded the entire selection and there is NO key frames below it.  So it's just a key frame on the header and no actual bones.

Comment: could you please share your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 2):

Turn your action editor into a standard Dopesheet, turn off its blue arrow tool and you will find the keyframed attribute, probably something like  a custom property, a material node or a constraint, as some of theese are not displayed into the action editor but in the standard dope sheet only.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Josh.  This wasn't the issue - But I'll look into this in the future.  My issue was there was a key frame inserted in Object mode.  That's why I couldn't see it on the armature level.  Blender could be confusing at times.

Comment: I,m glad you solved, because generally when you think it's a bug ... it's not  a bug!

Comment: Do you know why I wouldn't see this in the action editor vs the Dope sheet?  Is that a bug?

Comment: My guess is that the designers decided to keep separate what belongs to the rig strictly (and therefore can be easily exported in others engines, like Unity or Unreal Engine) from what belongs to the rest of Blender structure (and then needs more efforts to correctly export).